# Bandpass filter doesn't work when implementing PCB

Tags: pcb, rf, circuit-design, filter, passive-filter

I have been trying to make a 5th-order Chebyshev filter going from 500 MHz - 570 MHz and a 3rd-order Chebyshev filter going from 500 MHz - 540 MHz. This is my first time making a filter into a PCB.

No matter what I do, my physical implementation of it doesn't match my calculations and PSpice simulations.

I realize this circuit doesn't have the most perfect geometry and the parts have tolerances (I chose tolerances that should still work) but it should still be close enough. Why is the pass band so far off? The span on the spectrum analyzer screen is from 1 MHz to 1 GHz. The peak is seen at 350 MHz instead of 535 MHz which it should be.

I'm at my wits end. I have been stuck on this for a month now, please help.

[image]

---

Here is the board geometry. I have confirmed that the values are correct and should work even with their tolerances.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please post a schematic view of your PCB, what values you have tried, and also what sort of signal is going into your filter.

Comment: raaymaan I have added the schematic picture, i made sure my values were correct of course... just a simple sine wave is going into the circuit..

Comment: This is just a thought, but you may be pushing the limits of your inductors with how high your passband frequencies are. I would speculate that their SRFs are below your cutoff frequencies which may be causing the unwanted frequency shift. Hard to tell though without data sheets.

Comment: Ryan u are most likely correct. I realize that I didn't lay attention to the q factor or SRF(just learned what that is now lol)..

Comment: A valuable quote for RF design: "all parasitics are low-pass." That your measured pass-band is shifted low in frequency compared to simulation strongly suggests to me that your model is missing some parasitics. I can't tell what the components in your lumped schematic is supposed to represent, but if you're not accounting for stray parasitics in your PCB, that's likely the first place to check...

Comment: ...try adding some extra shunt capacitances to your schematic and see how much you need to add to match your measured response, then ascertain whether that amount seems like a reasonable contribution from your PCB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each track has both inductance, capacitance and resistance and thus a characteristic impedance from Z^2=L/C

I believe you only have trace inductance. That will not work.

There are ways that do work. I have always relied on coaxial resonators and SAW filters or coaxial 1/4 shorted notch filters.

[image] [REF](https://www.analogictips.com/rf-microwave-bandpass-filter-implementations-part-3-microstrip-coaxial-and-helical-filters/)

Note the Q's in this filter  > 1000 and the quality of the return loss.

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=8502815

Comment: I dont fully understand, why do my traces only have inductance in them and why does that skew the center frequency?

Comment: They should not be only inductance.  Are you going to do what I suggest? analyze each trace and compare with your schematic then show result in question

Comment: They aren't, there are capacitors in there

Comment: hmm even air is a capacitor

Comment: Okay I will analyze the taxes using the formula.. u think microstrips would be a better route?

Comment: I think you should show a better schematic and layout identifying all values,  parts , trace impedance assumptions and specs

Comment: Actually, wait, even if the traces are causing significant impedance mismatch that should only affect the gain of the passband, it should skew things off to the left, right?

Comment: I added the schematic recently.. so u have never done a simple LC filter? LC filters don't work in real life?

Comment: Go look inside a TV tuner.. They use air coils and PTC caps. IN FM Rdaos they use trimmer ferrite coils and air coils. You still need to learn more about properties of materials. The NTC of L is compensated by choosing PTC caps instead of NP0/C0G. That's why I used ceramic resonators and SAW filters and COAX stubs for VHF/UHF and stripline for > 1GHz on low loss tangent FR4

Comment: I definitely have a lot more to learn, thank you for the explanation. In the meantime if I replace the parts with large through hole parts with ferrite core inductors and pay attention to the parts q at the operating frequency(which I didn't for this BOM), do u think it would work? Or should I just do microstrips?

Comment: I think you should understand what does work and why 1st

Comment: There are many books on RF filters

Comment: That ieee link defines Q for you and explains the geometry in that design that contributes to each as a starter